# Piecewise continuity with countably infinite discontinuities

Tags: functions, continuity

If a function has countably infinite number of discontinuities, can it still be called piecewise continuous [say greatest integer function]? I read that a piecewise continuous has finitely many discontinuities.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I would say the greatest integer function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is piecewise continuous, despite having infinitely many discontinuities.  But the discontinuities have no cluster points.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by cluster points? Also do you mean to say countably infinite jump discontinuities can be taken as piecewise continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an interval extending to infinity, say $[0,\infty)$, a function is said to be piecewise continuous if it is piecewise continuous in every closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $[a,b]\subset[0,\infty)$.

Thus, the greatest integer function is piecewise continuous as in every finite interval, the points of discontinuity are finite and the left and right hand limits at these points are finite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take for example $f(x)=\frac 1 {cos(x)} $. It's discontinuous in all the points of the form of $\frac \pi 2 + k \pi$ but is still piecewise continuous in the open sets $(\frac \pi 2 + k \pi, \frac \pi 2 + (k+1)\pi)$ (it's quotient of elementary continuous function that don't vanish in the interval considered).